# Stats.d throws "connect ECONNREFUSED" error when graphite is on a different server

Tags: node.js, graphite, statsd

I have followed this tutorial to install and configure stats.d and Graphite :

http://www.elao.com/blog/linux/install-stats-d-graphite-on-a-debian-server-to-monitor-a-symfony2-application-12.html

However, my graphite can only see local agent and, when I start my statsd on another server, I have this error

```
30 Jan 10:50:29 - DEBUG: numStats: 3
30 Jan 10:50:29 - DEBUG: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Here is my stats.d local.js configuration file :

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "my.ip.add"
, port: 8125
, backends: [ "./backends/graphite" ]
, debug: true
, dumpMessages: true
}
```

It doesn't change anything wether I put the ip or the host of graphite.

Also, if this can help, the 2 servers (the one with stats.d and the one with graphite) are ovh kimsufi serveurs running Debian 7

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a node issue(statsd is a node application) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949277/getting-econnrefused-error-when-socket-connection-is-established-on-different):

> Set the server to bind to 0.0.0.0 and set the client to connect to the
>   correct IP address of the server. If the server is listening on
>   127.0.0.1, it will only accept connections from its local host.

```
ENABLE_UDP_LISTENER = True
UDP_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
UDP_RECEIVER_PORT = 2003
```

Comment: Yep but to launch stadsd, I simply exec "screen node stats.js local.js". I am not familiar with nodejs and don't really understand what to do :/

Comment: The issue is at Graphite end, i think. It seems that it is listening at `127.0.0.1` than `0.0.0.0`.